# Why CurrentApp::AppId take so long in Windows Phone 10?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx, windows-10-mobile

I have a windows 8 universal project and have a function to get APP ID,
The following function works well in Windows Phone 8.1

```
Platform::Guid  appId = Windows::ApplicationModel::Store::CurrentApp::AppId;
```

however, it spent around 40s in Windows Phone 10.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.appid.aspx), only the Metadata is different,

May I know is it caused by the metadata? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To instead of using `AppID`, you might use the following code,

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Package^ package = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current;
Windows::ApplicationModel::PackageId^ packageId = package->Id;
Windows::ApplicationModel::PackageVersion version = packageId->Version;

Platform::String^ output = 
  "Name: \"" + packageId->Name + "\"\n" +
  "Version: " + version.Major.ToString() + "." 
              + version.Minor.ToString() + "." 
              + version.Revision.ToString() + "." 
              + version.Build.ToString() + "\n" +
  "Architecture: " + packageId->Architecture.ToString() + "\n" +
  "ResourceId: \"" + packageId->ResourceId + "\"\n" +
  "Publisher: \"" + packageId->Publisher + "\"\n" +
  "PublisherId: \"" + packageId->PublisherId + "\"\n" +
  "FullName: \"" + packageId->FullName + "\"\n" +
  "FamilyName: \"" + packageId->FamilyName + "\"\n" +
  "IsFramework: " + package->IsFramework.ToString();
```

Sample output from device

`Output:
Name: "f3e02737-ddfa-47a0-a837-37ee53459898"
Version: 1.0.0.0
Architecture: Arm
ResourceId: ""
Publisher: "CN=heefan"
PublisherId: "gsbawe9kfjm1p"
FullName: "f3e02737-ddfa-47a0-a837-37ee53459898_1.0.0.0_arm__gsbawe9kfjm1p"
FamilyName: "f3e02737-ddfa-47a0-a837-37ee53459898_gsbawe9kfjm1p"
IsFramework: false`

I also have no idea why `AppID` take long time to compute.