# Are AppId and Package Id identical?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to open Windows Store of my current application (so the user can rate/review out app). In doing so, I need to get the App ID. However, I come across [this article in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748044/why-currentappappid-take-so-long-in-windows-phone-10) that says `CurrentApp.AppId` takes a lot of time, and offer Package ID as substitution. I have never released a app on Windows Store before, and cannot test it now without a released/published app on Windows Store.

Can anyone help me confirm about the following two lines of code?

```
        //var appId = CurrentApp.AppId.ToString();
        var appId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, [`AppId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.appid.aspx) and [`PackageId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.aspx) are not identical.

As you can see `AppId` is a `Guid` structure while `PackageId` is a class. `AppId` is generated by the Windows Store when your app has been certified for listing in the Windows Store, while `PackageId` provides package identification info, such as name, version, and publisher which can be found in your appx manifest.

As the `AppId` is related to the Windows Store, so the first time when you try to obtain it, it may takes some time. But this won't be too long, in my test it's around 1 second. After this, when you try to obtain the `AppId` again, it will be very quick. (I think it has been stored in local machine as its value is invariant.)

However, if you want to launches the product details page (PDP) for a product. Product ID is recommended for customers on Windows 10. And the Product ID is not the `AppId`.

To get the Product ID, as [Launch the Windows Store app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app) said:

> These values can be found in the Windows Dev Center dashboard on the [App identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt148561.aspx) page in the App management section for each app.

To get it programmatically, we can try to use [CurrentApp.LinkUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.linkuri.aspx) property, this property returns the URI of the app's listing page in the Windows Store like:

> `https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/<your app's Product ID>`.

The Product ID is also invariant, so I think you can just find it in Windows Dev Center dashboard and hardcode it in your app.

Comment: Can finish the job, for example in `c#` with `var id = uriLink.Substring(uriLink.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

Comment: @JayZuo I'm a bit confused about `Package Id`. Would you have time to comment or suggest a solution on my this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54384417/1232087)? The title of post from `@Luke Vo` seems to be about `Package Id vs AppID`. You mentioned `PackageId` as opposed to `Package Id` that is [Package.Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.id#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_Id) - a property of type Package (a class)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you want:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri($"ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN={Package.Current.Id.FamilyName}"));
```

The Store will handle the `ms-windows-store:` protocol, and the arguments will point it to your app's "Rate and Review" section.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed what I am needing. However, for future reference, I would love if there is a real answer to my question. If there is none tomorrow, I will change my question and mark yours as answer.

Comment: Also, according to this MSDN Article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 `Launches the product details page (PDP) for a product.
Product ID is recommended for customers on Windows 10, but earlier ways of doing it (ex: PFN) still work.` It says I should use Product ID?