# UWP App package information sample app - where it is showing package identity

Tags: c#, uwp

Using **VS2017 latest version 15.9.5** I successfully deployed this [UWP Package](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Package) sample (using their C# folder) from Microsoft's GitHub site on my **Windows 10 Pro ver 1809** laptop. But on the sample app's main window (shown below), when I click **1) Identity --> Get Package** it doesn't seem to show the package identity.

**Question**: What I may be missing or misunderstanding here?

**NOTE**: According to the above mentioned Microsoft article:

> > Each package is defined by a globally unique identifier known as the package identity. The sample covers following key tasks:

- Getting the package identity using Package.Id
- Getting the package directory using Package.InstalledLocation
- etc. etc.

**Sample app's main window when I run the sample**:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting confused with AppId? Package id is a object having all those details mentioned its not like an unique  id

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Package/cs/scenario2_installedlocation.xaml.cs shows how to get installed location

Comment: @AravindBelagaje I was a bit confused about Package Id as depicted in my comment on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920298/are-appid-and-package-id-identical#comment95582090_35937399). Response from user `Martin Zikmund` here helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PackageId` (see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packageid)) is not a simple string, but instead a full class having several properties which give you access to individual components which together make up the application's unique ID.

The most interesting for you might be `FullName`, which is the full unique identifier of  the specific version of your package, and `FamilyName` which is a version-agnostic identifier of your app.

The `PackageId` instance is accessible from `Package.Current.Id`.

However, if you want to generate a link to your app in the Store, you must instead hardcode the special Store ID which is generated for you in the Dev Center. You can find details for this [here in Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/link-to-your-app).

Comment: Glad it helped :-). Happy coding!

Comment: Nicely explained. Thank you for helping - while sitting from other side of the World (Magic of SO). I was confused about Package Identity as I wrote in a comment on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920298/are-appid-and-package-id-identical#comment95582090_35937399). Yes, indeed I was looking for the full unique identifier of the specific version of my package - that per your suggestion would be `FullName`